# How to forward spark log to jupyter notebook?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I know I can set up log level via `spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('INFO')` Logs such as the following appears in the terminal, but not in the jupyter notebook.

```
2019-03-25 11:42:37 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
2019-03-25 11:42:37 WARN  SparkConf:66 - In Spark 1.0 and later spark.local.dir will be overridden by the value set by the cluster manager (via SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS in mesos/standalone and LOCAL_DIRS in YARN).
2019-03-25 11:42:38 WARN  Utils:66 - Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
```

The spark session is created in local mode in the jupyter notebook cell.

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .master('local[7]') \
    .appName('Notebook') \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Is there any way to forward the logs to the jupyter notebook?

Comment: Hi, did you find a way?

Comment: Try using the logging module to create a logger and use it in DEBUG level